# Fire callback after cursors foreach function is done?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am using NodeJS to iterate over a large product collection. MongoDb native driver is used. Everything is fine but i want to write a footer line to a file after all documents are processed. How can i accomplish this?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var assert = require('assert');
var filename = '/tmp/' + feed.outputFilename;
fs.writeFileSync(filename, feed.header, feed.encoding, function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
});

var url = process.env.DB_HOST;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    var collection = db.collection('products');
    var cursor = collection.find({ "catalog": "electronics"}, { "batchSize": 1,fields: {} }).forEach(function(product) {
        if(product != null) {
            var child = workers[Math.floor(Math.random()*workers.length)];
            var data = {};
            data.product = product;
            data.feed = feed;
            child.send(data);
        }
    }, function(err) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.close();
    });

    // This doens't work for me (Error: Connot read property 'on' of undefined)
    /*cursor.on('end', function() {
        fs.appendFile('/tmp/' + filename, feed.footer, function(err) {
            if(err) throw err;
        });

        db.close();
    })*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what could be happening here is that the `value` returned from your call to `forEach` is being assigned into the `cursor` `var`.

Try assigning the `value` returned from the `find` into the `cursor` `var` and calling your `forEach` as `cursor.forEach` and `cursor.on` later.

Comment: I've rebuild the function to use the mongo stream interface to get this done. I think the cursor itself will not fire an end event.